# QtQuick: Resize two textfields with Elide on both

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I've got two Labels A and B in a row which need to be anchored together such that there is no spacing between them. A is not allowed to be larger than it's content, because B is like a detail label. It would be weird to see `Google Chrome_____(the current browser)`. You'll want `Google Chrome (the current browser)____` in this case.
Both have a common parent that they can fill up. Content-wise both A and B can be the larger of the two. The whole thing should be left aligned such that A is anchored to the parent's left and B.left == A.right.

When there is not enough space, both items should shrink and elide until they fit the parent, eg `Google Chr..(The current br...`

This last part is what I could not figure out how to do.

I'm using 2 labels instead of 1 because they need their own elision and their own styling.
My current solution will simply elide B, not shrink A at all.

```
RowLayout
        {
            spacing: 0
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: customisedSettings.left
            anchors.leftMargin: UM.Theme.getSize("default_margin").width

            Label
            {
                id: textLabelA
                text: qualityName()
                font: UM.Theme.getFont("default")
                color: UM.Theme.getColor("text")
                Layout.margins: 0
                height: contentHeight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                elide: Text.ElideRight

                function qualityName() {
                    [...]
                }
            }

            Label
            {
                id: textLabelDetail
                text: activeQualityDetailText()
                font: UM.Theme.getFont("default")
                color: UM.Theme.getColor("text_detail")
                anchors.verticalCenter: textLabelA.verticalCenter
                Layout.margins: 0
                Layout.fillWidth: true

                height: contentHeight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering
                elide: Text.ElideRight

                function activeQualityDetailText()
                {
                    [..]
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by putting them in a `RowLayout` and setting `Layout.fillWidth: true` on both of them so they both shrink.
To ensure that the first Label isn't larger than needed, set `Layout.maximumWidth: implicitWidth`.

This gives us :

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Label {
            text: "Google Chrome"

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.maximumWidth: implicitWidth

            elide: Text.ElideRight
        }
        Label {
            text: "(the current browser)"
            color: "darkgray"

            Layout.fillWidth: true

            elide: Text.ElideRight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks very promising! When applying it to the starter code I added, It breaks down when textLabelA has very little content though, eg 3 characters. In that case, textLabelA will be elided to 1 character and textLabelDetail will take the remaining space, even though the parent has ample space for both. Any idea why?

Comment: This doesn't happen in my code when replacing the first text by "abc". Try to edit your question to add a small reproducible example of this issue.

Comment: When I paste your code in a template QtQuick project in Qt Creator, the first label actually gets elided to Google Chro.... No matter the width of the window. So is this a problem with my environment? Using Qt Creator 4.10, runkit Desktop Qt 5.12.2 GCC 64bit on Ubuntu Linux 64bit